# apply value inner.Width and inner.Height to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-resolution

Basic question...

How can I apply the values of innerWidth and innerHeight to body, so it adapts to the screen resolution?! making it responsive.

How do you write this in Javascript/jquery?! Example if possible...

EDIT//// THIS WOULD BE THE CODE?

Would this make the magic happen?!?!

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var h = $(window).height();
     var w = $(window).width();

     $('body').css({"height": h+'px', "width": w+'px'});
});
```

Comment: The default width value of the BODY element is "auto", and since it's a block-level element, that means that by default, the BODY element fills up all horizontal space, so that is already taken care of.

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero You can use `css` for this: `body {height: 100%, width: 100%}`

Answer (score 3):

> `.innerWidth()`  method returns the width of the element, including left and right padding, in pixels. This method is not applicable to `window` and `document` objects; for these, use `.width()` instead.

```
var h = $(window).height();
var w = $(window).width();

$('body').css({"height": h+'px', "width": w+'px'});
```

Comment: thanks... simple and direct AT LAST!!! Another stupid questions is... If I want to test if it works which is the best method?!!? Do I need other computers?!?!

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero No, this is not a ... question, resize the browser and refresh the page.

Comment: He undefined. I tried the code above, resized the window and refreshed. This is not working as wished. There is no difference... Have I've done something wrong?!

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero Are your sure there is no error on the console and jQuery is loaded correctly?